# How can I exclude records containing N/A values using read_sql with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading a SQLite3 database with pandas. There are some items missing marked with N/A. I read it using read_sql. If it was a csv there is na_values option and then I would use dropna. I know I can use filters to take out the rows containing N/A. Is there a similar option to na_values ?

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3

database = 'mydatabase.db'
con = sqlite3.connect(database)
con.text_factory = str
curs = con.cursor()

with con:
    sql = """SELECT NAME, AGE, EDUCATION_LEVEL FROM Data"""
    df = pd.read_sql(sql, con, index_col='ID')
```

Comment: it's not a kwarg atm, perhaps post a feature request on github? For now, munging in pandas after `read_sql` is probably best bet.